# How to install selenium using python3?

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, setuptools, python-3.6

After extracting .tar.gz and running `python setup install`, selenium gets installed in,

```
....
creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium-3.4.3-py2.7.egg
Extracting selenium-3.4.3-py2.7.egg to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Adding selenium 3.4.3 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium-3.4.3-py2.7.egg
.....
```

---

On running,

```
python functionalTest.py
```

it works fine

But

```
python3.6 functionalTest.py
```

gives, error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

because I could not install selenium using python3.6 on Ubuntu, successfully, as shown below,

```
$ ls setup*
setup.cfg  setup.py
$ python3.6 setup install
python3.6: can't open file 'setup': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
$ python3.6 setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 22, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
.....
Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 22, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
$
```

**Edit:**

After installing setuptools, below is the observation,

```
$ python3.6 setup.py install
.....
creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium-3.4.3-py2.7.egg
Extracting selenium-3.4.3-py2.7.egg to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
selenium 3.4.3 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium-3.4.3-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for selenium==3.4.3
Finished processing dependencies for selenium==3.4.3
$ cd /usr/local/lib/python
python2.7/ python3.5/ python3.6/ 
$ 
$ easy_install --version
setuptools 20.7.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (Python 2.7)
$ pip --version
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
$
```

---

**Question:**

How to configure for python3.6 to pick selenium?  Why selenium is installed in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7` despite using `python3.6`?

Comment: hi, run : `python3.6 setup install` to install selenium for python3.6 , then try running

Comment: Why not use pip?

Comment: @Stack On saying `python3.6 setup.py install` I get error, `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'` from code `from setuptools import setup`

Comment: @AlexHall Does pip make sure that python3 & 2 pick selenium smoothly?

Comment: @overexchange , you can use pip , try  `pip3 install selenium` or `python3.6 -m pip install selenium` , it should work

Comment: @overexchange Not sure what OS you are running but for the error with setup.py for Python 3 you will need to get the setuptools. You can get them by running the following command (assuming linux or MacOS)

`sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have multiple versions of Python installed. Based on the logs that you've provided it appears that you have installed Selenium into your Python 2.7 install.

If you have changed Python 3 to run in your cmd with the command "python3.6" then you should run the setup by doing:

```
python3.6 setup install
```